# Attached external pdf file is not showing page number

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, pdfpages

I am writing my thesis. I have a "main" LaTeX file from where I am calling (attaching) `pdf` file. But the attached `pdf` file is not showing any page number. Also, it is not showing other page style I have (like, color vertical box at right end of the page, for chapter name). How this problem can be solved ?

```
%=======================================

\documentclass[11pt, b5paper,twoside, svgnames]{thesis}

% "thesis" uses book class

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%---------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{RESULTS}
\includepdf[scale=0.9, pages={-}]{results.pdf}


\end{document}



%======================================
% HEADER and FOOTER
%---------------------------------------

\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}{\slshape \leftmark}

%=======================================================
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using your current settings, the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) inserts the pages of an external PDF file as full page *additions* to your existing document. That is, the external file page setup is copied to the "main" output PDF on a page-by-page basis. The "main" file's page setup (including header/footer) is ignored.

If you wish to include the same header/footer style of your main document for each of the `\includepdf` pages, then you need to specify this using the `pagecommand` key-value:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Something}
\includepdf[scale=0.9,pages={-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{results}
\end{document}
```

Also note that [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)'s `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` only takes *one* mandatory argument: `\fancyfoot[<page spec>]{<stuff>}`.

Comment: `pagecommand={}` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

By default `pdfpages` uses the options `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}`.

if you want the pagestyle on the included pages you need to call `includepdf` like :

```
 \includepdf[scale=0.9,pages={-},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{results.pdf}
```