# Graphics are hiding page numbers

Tags: graphics, page-numbering

I have several pdfs included in my tex file (actually its a song book). Unfortunately the pdfs are hiding the page numbers:

```
\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{/Users/anti/Documents/2013/Liederbuch/Lieder/Testbuk/EdisLiederbuch-page12.pdf}
```

Is there a possibility to lay the page numbers over the graphics?

Thanks in advance!

Andreas

Comment: Perhaps you're after a solution of the form presented in [Attached external PDF file is not showing page number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50388/5764)?

Comment: may be `\includegraphics[page=10,scale=0.5]{}` could work

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `\includepdf` belongs to the `pdfpages` package,
it uses by default an option `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}`.
To get the page numbers, this option should be changed. For example, the command

```
\includepdf[fitpaper=true,pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{pdfin}
```

includes all pages from the file `pdfin.pdf` and prints the page numbers 
according to pagestyle `plain`.